# Why does this RABL node return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

```
node :transitType do |u|
    :Entry if u.type == 'HorseEntryTransit'
    :Exit  if u.type == 'HorseExitTransit'
end
```

I tried the following and this code snippet returns true.

```
node :transitType do |u|
    u.type == 'HorseEntryTransit'
end
```

Comment: what outputs when you change the line to simply `u.type`?

Comment: I see the value of u.type (e.g. HorseExitTransit) when I change last line to u.type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the code block and avoid testing two conditions ( when the first one is met). Also, presume a case where neither condition is met.  It looks like you would get `nil` when the second condition fails even though the first condition was true.

```
 node :transitType do |u|
     if u.type == 'HorseEntryTransit'
          :Entry 
     elsif u.type == 'HorseExitTransit'
          :Exit
     else
          nil #or :Neither
     end
end
```

Your code does not work when the first condition is actually met since the second condition will still be tested and the result of that condition is `nil`.

Comment: +1 for your answer; thanks.  I was hoping to learn why my code does not work.

Comment: added some clarification of why your code returns nil